# Excel VBA for setting specific cell values based on user choice

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for help to improve the efficiency of my VBA code here.
Not sure how i can set it up that if i have 10 row in B (B5 to B10), that it will automatically populate the:

- D column of that row if the value of B is 1,
- update D and E if the value of B is 2,
- and update D,E, and F if the value of B if 3

Without manually specifying it row by row in the code itself

Example:

-If i set value of B9 as 2, it populate the values of the cells D9 and E9

-If i set value of B6 as 1, it populate the value of the cell D6

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B5")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = 1
            Range("D5").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
        Case Is = 2
            Range("D5").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
            Range("E5").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
        Case Is = 3
            Range("D5").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
            Range("E5").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
            Range("F5").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
        Case Else
            Range("D5:F5").Value = ""
    End Select
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B6")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = 1
            Range("D6").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
        Case Is = 2
            Range("D6").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
            Range("E6").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
        Case Is = 3
            Range("D6").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
            Range("E6").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
            Range("F6").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
        Case Else
            Range("D6:F6").Value = ""
    End Select
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B7")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = 1
            Range("D7").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
        Case Is = 2
            Range("D7").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
            Range("E7").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
        Case Is = 3
            Range("D7").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
            Range("E7").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
            Range("F7").Value = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & "• No. of Activities Affected:"
        Case Else
            Range("D7:F7").Value = ""
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, perhaps the following using `Resize` and `Target.Row`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B5:B10")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim rw As Long
        rw = Target.Row

        Dim txt As String
        txt = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & _
              "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & _
              "• No. of Activities Affected:"

        Select Case Target.Value
            Case 1 To 3
                Me.Range("D" & rw).Resize(, Target.Value).Value = txt
            Case Else
                Me.Range("D" & rw & ":F" & rw).Value = ""
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: if i set a value of 2 for B5, it populates 2 cells with the data. If i was to add additional text to that cell it gets removed if i update B5 to 1. It resets the text values. Is there a way to save changes if the change is still within range?

Comment: Yes. Sounds like the code should only add the text if the range in question is currently empty?

Comment: Might be worth asking that as a new question since I'm not sure I understand the details. Feel free to ping me here with the link too.

Comment: Link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58944737/excel-vba-keep-text-changes-of-data-when-cell-is-still-within-resize-range