# Keep text changes of data when cell is still within resize range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA Macro that is setting the values of cells based on user input from specific cells in range.
However if I add text to the cell that was updated, if I change the user value it wipes my additional text.

For Example:

I set B5 as 2, which populates D5 and E5 with the following text values:

- Course Name:
- No. Of Slides Affected:
- No. of Activities Affected:

If I update the D5 with additional text in the cell etc. Course Name: abc, and update the value of B5 to 1. D5 is still within the range, but it deletes the additional text I just entered.

How can I set it so that it doesn't reset the text values if they have been edited when I reduce or increase the value of B5?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B5:B50")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim rw As Long
        rw = Target.Row

        Dim txt As String
        txt = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & _
              "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & _
              "• No. of Activities Affected:"

        Select Case Target.Value
            Case 1 To 5
                Me.Range("D" & rw).Resize(, Target.Value).Value = txt
            Case Else
                Me.Range("D" & rw & ":H" & rw).Value = ""
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Check the length of the value of D5. If there is something in it, don't put anything there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const NUM_COLS As Long = 5
    Const TXT = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & _
              "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & _
              "• No. of Activities Affected:"

    Dim rng As Range, i As Long, v

    If Target.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B5:B50")) Is Nothing Then

        Set rng = Target.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, NUM_COLS) 'range to check
        v = Target.Value

        If IsNumeric(v) And v >= 1 And v <= NUM_COLS Then
            For i = 1 To rng.Cells.Count
                With rng.Cells(i)
                    If i <= v Then
                        'Populate if not already populated
                        If .Value = "" Then .Value = TXT
                    Else
                        'Clear any existing value
                        .Value = ""
                    End If
                End With
            Next i
        Else
            rng.Value = "" 'clear any existing content
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How would I use the values I set in B5:B50 in this sheet in a macro from another sheet? I want to use the value from B5 for instance in this macro to populate another range of cells with another const txt in another sheet.

Comment: Instead of `Me` you would reference the other sheet, either using its tab name or its codename.